# Struggling to get convergence to Euler's number

Tags: matlab, graph, convergence, eulers-number

Hi there I’ve been working on trying to plot the convergence of 'e' through using the equation 1/N! with limits from 0 to 9.

```
clc,clear
terms=[1];
x=10;
for i=2:x
    terms(i,1)=terms(i-1,1) + 1/factorial(i);
end
disp(terms)
xplotrange = 0:9;
plot(xplotrange,terms,'b-')
```

With the code I intened to plot the number of terms in the 'x' axis and the result of the series in the 'y' axis. But I am confused as to why the array of numbers outputted in the for loop converges at 1.718 instead of 2.718?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61173123/12158757) stated, [Euler's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)) via Taylor expansion should start from `x=0` . Thus you can adjust your code to something like below

```
terms=[1];
x=10;
for i=2:x
    terms(i,1)=terms(i-1,1) + 1/factorial(i-1);
end
disp(terms)
xplotrange = 0:9;
plot(xplotrange,terms,'b-')
```

or a method using `cumsum`, e.g.,

```
terms=[1];
x=10;
terms = cumsum(1./factorial(0:x));
disp(terms)
xplotrange = 0:x;
plot(xplotrange,terms,'b-');
```

Answer (score 2):

Initializing `terms` with `1` and starting your for loop at `2`, you effectively start at `i=1`, but the sum has to start at `i=0`. `1/0!` is the `1` you are missing.